# bucardo unable to connect to other DBs

Tags: postgresql, authentication, debian, database-replication, bucardo

I experience some problems using `bucardo add db` command. It looks like it's unable to connect to other postgreSQL databases. 
I tried to do it in several ways. With **pg_hba.conf** setting

"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only:
**local all postgres ident**

```
/usr/local/src/bucardo-5.3.1# ./bucardo add db cd_db dbname=hq
```

*Connection to "cd_db" (PostgreSQL database) as user bucardo failed. You may force add it with the --force argument.
Error was: fe_sendauth: no password supplied*

Then with pg_hba.conf setting

"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only:
**local all all peer**

with postgres credentials:

```
/usr/local/src/bucardo-5.3.1# ./bucardo add db cd_db dbname=hq db dbuser=postgres
```

*Connection to "cd_db" (PostgreSQL database) as user postgres failed. You may force add it with the --force argument.
Error was: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"*

with bucardo credentials:

```
/usr/local/src/bucardo-5.3.1# ./bucardo add db cd_db dbname=hq db dbuser=bucardo dbpass=bucardo-runner
```

*Connection to "cd_db" (PostgreSQL database) as user bucardo failed.
Error was: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "bucardo"*

Please help me to figure out what is wrong and how to use the installed bucardo.
I'm running it on Linux Debian, just for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ident to login with a different user other than the linux user you will need to map the user in pg_ident.conf.

```
pg_indet.conf
app             root                    postgres
app             root                    bucardo
app             {username}              bucardo

pg_hba.conf
local   all         all                                     ident map=app
```